# How do you pronounce these sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm making a video on Rudin's proof that closed subsets of compact sets are compact. How do you pronounce:

$$
\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}
$$

or, more succinctly, just:

$$
\{V_\alpha\}
$$

Thank you!

Comment: vee-alpha, or vee-sub-alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A family of sets $V_\alpha$ (pronounced *vee-alpha*) where alpha lies in $A$.

Comment: Thank you! When the indexing set A is obvious, as in, just {}, I take it I can read this as "A family of sets vee-alpha". rubikscube09's answer (simply "vee-alpha") seems like it would refer to just a single set rather than the whole family.

Comment: Yes, you are right!